# Regarding line of code

Tags: java, string, collections, io

Modified the code this time the objective to count the line of code was perfect below is the piece of code..

```
 /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    private static int totalLineCount = 0;
    private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Map<File, Integer> result = new HashMap<File, Integer>();
            File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

            List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);

            // print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
            for (File file : files) {
               // System.out.println("Directory: " + file);
                getFileLineCount(result, file);
                //totalFileScannedCount += result.size(); //saral
            }

            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
            System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey().getAbsolutePath() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);
        }

    }


    public static void getFileLineCount(final Map<File, Integer> result, final File directory)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            public boolean accept(final File directory, final String name) {
                if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                totalFileScannedCount ++; //saral
                try {

                    /*for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null;lineCount++ ) { //saral
                        ;


                    }*/


                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                           String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                           if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                              System.out.println("debug-->"+line); // to debug cross checked that no whitespaces are there 
                             lineCount++;
                           }
                    }

                     result.put(file, lineCount);
                     totalLineCount += lineCount;                               
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all Files found;
     * the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
     * 
     * @param aStartingDir
     *            is a valid directory, which can be read.
     */
    static public List<File> getFileListing(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    // PRIVATE //
    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file);
            }
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                // must be a directory
                // recursive call!
                List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be
     * read.
     */
    static private void validateDirectory(final File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (aDirectory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
        }
        if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
        }
    }
```

but the issue is that when it is displaying the result on console it throws the below exception please advise how to overcome from that

```
*****************************************
FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC
*****************************************
C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\fg\src\asd\abv.java ==> 9
*****************************************
SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>    1
SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>    9
Exception while removing reference: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: My first advice to you would be to refactor your code to be smaller methods.

Comment: to overcome from this error I have removed the e.printstack trace statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
totalLineCount += lineCount;
```

in a catch block, but inside the try block I don't see anything that would cause NoSuchElementException to be thrown. Move the catch block code to the try block, the code doesn't seem to be appropriate as an exceptio handler. At least if you still want to execute it even though an exception occurs, put it in a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are updating the `totalLineCount` inside the `catch` block. Move it outside.

```
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                result.put(file, lineCount); // <-- 
                totalLineCount += lineCount; // <--  
            }
```

to

```
              result.put(file, lineCount); 
              totalLineCount += lineCount;   
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only updating totalLineCount when a NoSuchElement exception occurs. You should move it outside the try catch statement or put it in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, try to understand what I have done to make your code work-

```
 public class LineCount{ 
private static int totalLineCount = 0;
private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        Map<File, Integer> result = new HashMap<File, Integer>();
        File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

        List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);


        // print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
        for (File file : files) {
           // System.out.println("Directory: " + file);
            result  = getFileLineCount(result, file);
            totalFileScannedCount += result.size(); //saral
        }

        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");

        for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().getAbsolutePath() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
        System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);
    }

}


public static Map<File, Integer> getFileLineCount(final Map<File, Integer> result, final File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException {


    if (file.isFile()) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
            int lineCount = 0;
           // totalFileScannedCount ++; //saral
            try {
                /*for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; ) { //saral
                    ;


                }*/


                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                       String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                       if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                           System.out.println("debug-->"+line); // to debug cross checked that no whitespaces are there 
                         lineCount++;
                       }
                }


            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {


            }
            result.put(file, lineCount);
            totalLineCount += lineCount;
        }
    return result;
    }

//}

/**
 * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all Files found;
 * the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
 * 
 * @param aStartingDir
 *            is a valid directory, which can be read.
 */
static public List<File> getFileListing(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
    List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}

// PRIVATE //
static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(final File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        public boolean accept(final File directory, final String name) {
            if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });


    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);

    for (File file : filesDirs) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            result.add(file);
        }
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            // must be a directory
            // recursive call!
            List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be
 * read.
 */
static private void validateDirectory(final File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (aDirectory == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
    }
    if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
    }
    if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
    }
    if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
    }
}

}
```

I put the above java file in a folder and ran this code - 
The result is as follows -

---

FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC

---

/home/hkr/Desktop/LineCount.java ==> 129

---

SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>    1
SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>    129

Comment: could you please update the correct code and post it that will make understanding more clear , thanks a lot for updating

Comment: tried also by updating if (file.isDirectory()) { // This must be isFile() and not is directory to isfile() but throws error